# Arrays FindMax What am I missing?

Tags: java

I have a project that says,"Write a program to read a list of integer numbers and print the largest number among them.

For example: if user enters: 9 11 15 3 7 9

it prints out 15.

What am I missing? Here is the output[image: Test 1 have yet to find the final one]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the list");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int[] list = new int[size];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int max = list[0];
        for (i = 0; i > size; i++) {
            if (list[i] > max)
                max = list[i];
        }
        System.out.println(max);

    }
}
```

Comment: `for ( i=0; i > size; i++)` ?

Comment: Also, you do not need two loops.

Comment: A debugger is usually a good tool for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second loop:

```
for ( i=0; i > size; i++)
```

It should be while `i` is **SMALLER** than size:

```
for ( i=0; i < size; i++)
```

Otherwise, it skips that loop and returns the default maximum which you set at `list[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it